# How to change icon of cluster

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a map-based application, using Google Maps' iOS SDK. I need to change cluster icon as it is showing circle image on clusters.As in googlemap SDK Circles are creating in which number of markers are shown.How can i change icon of cluster as it is showing brown circle?Kindly plz help me i need it anxiously.Below is Cluster Creating code

```
- (UIImage*) generateClusterIconWithCount:(NSUInteger)count {

    int diameter = 40;
    float inset = 3;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.8] setStroke];
    [[UIColor brownColor] setFill];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, inset);

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, inset, inset);

    // draw circle
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName( (CFStringRef)@"Helvetica-Bold", 18.0f, NULL);

    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (__bridge id)myFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                    [UIColor whiteColor], (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    // create a naked string
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)count];

    NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                                       attributes:attributesDict];

    // flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, diameter);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)(stringToDraw));
    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(
                                                                        frameSetter, /* Framesetter */
                                                                        CFRangeMake(0, stringToDraw.length), /* String range (entire string) */
                                                                        NULL, /* Frame attributes */
                                                                        CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter), /* Constraints (CGFLOAT_MAX indicates unconstrained) */
                                                                        NULL /* Gives the range of string that fits into the constraints, doesn't matter in your situation */
                                                                        );
    CFRelease(frameSetter);

    //Get the position on the y axis
    float midHeight = diameter;
    midHeight -= suggestedSize.height;

    float midWidth = diameter / 2;
    midWidth -= suggestedSize.width / 2;

    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
            (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)stringToDraw);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, midWidth, 12);
    CTLineDraw(line, ctx);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: do You want change the color ?

Comment: not colour i want to add icon rather then creating circle...

Comment: I will post the ans little bit modified your method try! Once inform me it is work or not

Comment: always welcome Mishal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This !

```
-(UIImage*) generateClusterIconWithCount:(NSUInteger)count {

    int diameter = 40;
    float inset = 3;



    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
   // [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.8] setStroke];
   // [[UIColor brownColor] setFill];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, inset);

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, inset, inset);
    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];
    [titleImage drawInRect:circleRect];
    // draw circle
    //CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
   // CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName( (CFStringRef)@"Helvetica-Bold", 18.0f, NULL);

    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    (__bridge id)myFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor], (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    // create a naked string
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)count];

    NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                                       attributes:attributesDict];

    // flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, diameter);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)(stringToDraw));
    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(
                                                                        frameSetter, /* Framesetter */
                                                                        CFRangeMake(0, stringToDraw.length), /* String range (entire string) */
                                                                        NULL, /* Frame attributes */
                                                                        CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter), /* Constraints (CGFLOAT_MAX indicates unconstrained) */
                                                                        NULL /* Gives the range of string that fits into the constraints, doesn't matter in your situation */
                                                                        );
    CFRelease(frameSetter);

    //Get the position on the y axis
    float midHeight = diameter;
    midHeight -= suggestedSize.height;

    float midWidth = diameter / 2;
    midWidth -= suggestedSize.width / 2;

    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
                                                      (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)stringToDraw);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, midWidth, 12);
    CTLineDraw(line, ctx);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: If i want to less font value then wat can i do ?? means the font value is bigger than image ??

Comment: can i change this statement? CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName( (CFStringRef)@"Helvetica-Bold", 18.0f, NULL);

Comment: Yes if you want  change font name and font size  do it no problem

Comment: I HAD changed with this..CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName( (CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 13.0f, NULL); but text is not showing in centre ???

Comment: Change the int diameter = 40; to int diameter = 30;

Comment: Modify the diameter depending on font name and font size